# Организация запросов на сервер

Tags: android, android-sdk, сервер

Год назад начал изучал азы программирования по android. И в то же время не нашел ясной и понятной организации соединения с сервером. Читал про Service, но, как я понял, он необходим для кратковременного соединения и самое главное там не понятно как обрабатывать ответ, потом еще ее отправить на главный поток. Решил реализовать запросы с помощью Thread + HttpUrlConnection. Сделал это так:  https://github.com/VladimirPesterev/inFermer/blob/master/src/com/infermer/network/HttpConnectionToServer.java

Создал обычный класс у которого все методы статичны. Есть публичные методы которые я вызываю в главном потоке, чтобы создать соединение, он принимает параметры POST запроса и Context активити с которого он вызывается. Далее все эти методы вызывают приватный метод httpRequest, который просто создает новый поток анонимный и создает наконецто соединение с помощью класса HttpUrlConnection. Далее после того как мы получили ответ с сервера, проверяем успешный он или нет. Далее отправляем его в другой приватный метод в котором вызывается метод интерфейса onServerResponse реализованного в активити содержащий этот контекст. Вот для чего я возился с этим Context. Чтобы вызвать метод интерфейса реализованного в Activity с которого произошел вызов соединения. Вот и все.

Минусы в такой архитектуре есть. Например повторение запроса и т.д. И все же как правильно создать соединение? Хочу увидеть best practic от гуру-android-а. Всякие Volley не предлагать без обоснованной аргументации.

Answer (score 1):

1. Плохо читали про сервисы, как раз таки в серсвисы убирают и долгие фоновые работы, хоть с сетями, хоть с чем то другим.
2. в Volley ничего плохого нет, все таки best practice это REST для таких вещей.
3. У тебя есть еще один минус, что будет если я сделаю вызов из активти, а потом разверну девайс во время выполнения запроса на сервер. ?

при попытке вернуть ответ, на какой контекст он будет ссылаться ?

Это еще одна из причин, почему лучше выкинуть на сторону сервиса, так как он не будет связан с жизненным циклом активити и фрагментов(тут есть оговорки ввиде retain instance).

И дополнение небольшое, используй AsyncTask, он более заточен под ведроид с его жизненными циклами.